# Python Web Scrape Query DIV data-brand

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to grab a div tag in an html page, but the result is showing an empty list.  I've provided the code and a picture of the html.  The page_text variable is an empty list.

```
url = 'https://www.highspeedinternet.com/in-your-area?zip=50648'
                                
page = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
page_text = doc.find_all("div", {"data-brand"})
print(page_text)
```

[image: html code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to your goal, just add `True` as value in your `dict`:

```
doc.find_all('div',{"data-brand":True})
```

As alternative you can go with `css selectors` and `list comprehension` to get all the values:

```
[e.get('data-brand') for e in doc.select('div[data-brand]')]
```

Output:

```
['CenturyLink', 'Rise Broadband', 'LTD Broadband LLC', 'Viasat', 'HughesNet', 'Heartland Technology', 'Ooma', 'CenturyLink', 'Rise Broadband', 'LTD Broadband LLC', 'Viasat', 'HughesNet', 'Ooma', 'Heartland Technology', 'T-Mobile', 'Verizon Wireless', 'AT&T Wireless', 'Mint', 'Visible']
```